# How to automatically commit & push git changes using vs code extensions/source control?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-commit, git-push

I want to automatically message commit(or some way to commit with no message or even just any character it doesnt matter) & commit & push automatically in vscode git source control feature and git downloaded for windows to appropriate repo and branches whenever contents are changed.
I have a main branches for all my folders for different repos and test branches i just want to commit and push to the test branches so that they are always up to date
(i just started using git a few days ago i found a similar post but it was for push only)

Comment: write a shell script that does the job with `git` commands and create a task that calls this script and create a key binding that calls this task. Commits without any useful message are useless and how are you going to solve conflicts automatically